# Using IndexMap with serde_json

Tags: rust, serde-json

I would like to use `serde_json` to parse a `.json` file into a `IndexMap`. However it says the `Deserialize` trait has not been implemented for `IndexMap`. Is there a way to use `serde_json` with `IndexMap`?

```rs
let elements: IndexMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(r#"
        {
            "Hydrogen       (H) ": 1,
            "Helium         (He)": 4,
            "Lithium        (Li)": 7,
            "Beryllium      (Be)": 9,
            "Boron          (B) ": 11,
            "Carbon         (C) ": 12,
            "Nitrogen       (N) ": 14,
            "Oxygen         (O) ": 16,
            "Flourine       (F) ": 19,
            "Neon           (Ne)": 20
        }
    "#).expect("err: unable to parse json");
```

Comment: If this is from the "indexmap" crate, there is a ["serde" feature flag](https://docs.rs/crate/indexmap/latest/features) that probably enables this functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To deserialize index map you need either feature flag `serde` or `serde-1`.

*main.rs*

```rust
use indexmap::IndexMap;
use serde_json::Value;

fn main() {
    let elements: IndexMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(r#"
        {
            "Hydrogen       (H) ": 1,
            "Helium         (He)": 4,
            "Lithium        (Li)": 7,
            "Beryllium      (Be)": 9,
            "Boron          (B) ": 11,
            "Carbon         (C) ": 12,
            "Nitrogen       (N) ": 14,
            "Oxygen         (O) ": 16,
            "Flourine       (F) ": 19,
            "Neon           (Ne)": 20
        }
    "#).expect("err: unable to parse json");
    eprintln!("{:?}", elements);
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
indexmap = {version = "1.9.1", features = ["serde-1"]}
```